# what is the correct way to force existing activities to reload using the new local

Tags: android

have a settings dialog/activity where I allow the user to change the locale.  Within that activity i call

```
 Resources res = ctx.getResources(); 
// Change locale settings on the device 
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics(); 
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration(); 
conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase(), 
coutry_code.toUpperCase()); 
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

and call onChanged() for my settings ListView...  everything changes 
perfectly.  Very nice. 
Then I hit the back button to go back to the previous activity 
thinking everything should be switched; nope.  Everything is still in 
the previous locale.  So I added the above code in the onResume() of 
the activity thinking that would do it; nope.  Also, when I click the 
menu button of this activity again (not first time) I do not get 
called in onCreateOptionsMenu() it just displays the previous menu. 
My question is what is the correct way to force existing activities to 
reload using the new local?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly, but this seems to be an overhead. The standart way of swithicng locales is through the system settings. Let the user switch the locale there and just use `Locale.getDefault()` in your code.

Comment: can I  direct call the setting ui  in my app,instead of  use systerm  menu to call the  system settings.

Answer (score 0):

An OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in the parent activity is the correct place to respond to the change in preferences. As for refreshing the UI, I'm not entirely sure. We're told to let android manage the lifecycle of our activities for us but imho that's not always going to work. One option is to call onCreate() from onSharedPreferenceChanged.

Edit: Sorry, this listener probably won't work as you're not talking about a shared preference.